# Is this the correct way to "forward" an image request with streaming?

Tags: c#, stream, httprequest

I am implementing an API Controller that needs to function as a gateway for retrieving images. Later on, this gateway needs to check if a user is authorized to get the image but for now, only streaming the image is implemented and my question is, as I don't want to implement my streaming gateway the bad way: is this the right way to do it or is there a better way?

This is currently the code:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string objectId, string sessionId, string path)
    {
        var url = "An url to a jpeg or any other image";
        var copyOfStream = new MemoryStream();

        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        var getImageResponse = request.GetResponse();

        try
        {

            var stream = getImageResponse.GetResponseStream();
            stream.CopyTo(copyOfStream);
        }
        finally
        {
            getImageResponse.Close();
        }

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StreamContent(copyOfStream)
        };

        var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Path.GetExtension(".jpg"));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);

        return ResponseMessage(response);
    }
```

Any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it differently to get rid of some parts which are rather bothering:

1. Disposable objects are left undisposed and may leak.
2. The image binary data is fully loaded into memory and is served from there
3. NOTE: Please note that the current implementation will always serve 0 bytes because you are not calling `copyOfStream.Position = 0` before feeding it to the response
4. It is a read-all / write-all approach which will be slower than "write as you read"

So here is a suggested solution which:

1. Uses `HttpRequestMessage.RegisterForDispose` extension to register the disposable objects for disposal when the current request completes,
2. Writes the data to the response stream in chunks as it is read from the target web site (if Web API framework works like that, which is highly likely)

I hope this helps:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string objectId, string sessionId, string path)
    {
        var url = "An url to a jpeg or any other image";

        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);

        var getImageResponse = request.GetResponse();

        // Register the WebResponse for late disposal
        Request.RegisterForDispose(getImageResponse);

        Stream inputStream = getImageResponse.GetResponseStream();

        // Register the response stream for late disposal
        Request.RegisterForDispose(inputStream);

        // We haven't read anything from the wire yet:
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StreamContent(inputStream)
        };

        var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Path.GetExtension(".png"));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);

        return ResponseMessage(response);
    }
```

Comment: Which using do I need for RegisterForDispose? When I google it, the results I get states I need to use System.Net.Http which I have, yet it doesn't seem to find the extension method.

Comment: Namespace:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
Assembly:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll

Comment: Isn't this a Asp.Net Web API project?

Comment: For .Net Framework check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh969063(v%3Dvs.108)

Comment: Yes, it is a Web API project using the .NET Framework 4.7.2. The link you gave me in your last post is also the link I found earlier, which states I should use System.Net.Http. I got this assembly in my references and I have the using in my file. Yet it doesn't seem to recognize unfortunately.

Comment: I have it working now. Appearently I was attempting to pass in the wrong object and for some reason it didnt tell me I was doing that but instead I got the error that it couldnt find the extension method which put me on the wrong track. Thank you for helping out.

Comment: Oh yes, tries to match an extension by assumed method signature. :)